# Issue with converting yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z' in NodeJS (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetimeformatter

I am trying to run the following code:

```
// Included the data time formatter
var DateTimeFormatter = require('datetimeformatter');

var inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
var outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
var date = LocalDate.parse(gDate, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
var formattedDate = outputFormatter.format(date);
Console.out(formattedDate);
```

when I run the code i get the following `TypeError: DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern is not a function`

From searching online that is not accurate, ofPattern should be a function!?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't use `momentjs` https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: Which library is datetimeformatter? Have you got any links? Are you sure this is something that works with javascript?

Comment: @LihnNguyen moment.js is no longer maintained. Instead, date-fns can be a good choice.

Comment: DateTimeFormatter is java, not javascript; but you also tagged Node which is  javascript, not java.  What language are you actually trying to code in?

Comment: @DanielBeck javascript

Comment: If this is JavaScript, then why would you write `System.out.println`? Also, where do you see that `ofPattern` should exist? The [docs for the `datetimeformatter` package you use](https://www.npmjs.com/package/datetimeformatter) only show a `toString` method. I'm guessing you accidentally looked at [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-) instead? Do remember that **Java and JavaScript are two entirely different languages**!

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
npm install date-and-time
```

Example usage:

```js
const date = require('date-and-time')
const bd = new Date();
const value = date.format(bd,'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss');
console.log("current date and time : " + value)
```

Comment: How can I convert the following `2022-09-09T00:20Z` to `yyyyMMdd` with your example

Comment: I get the following error : `NodeJS/node_modules/date-and-time/date-and-time.js:171
            offset = dateObj.getTimezoneOffset(),`

Answer (score 0):

Included code seems to suggest you are trying to run Java code.
You can extract the date string for example:

```
const newTime = new Date('2022-09-09T00:20Z').toLocaleDateString('en-gb');
```

You can modify the output result more, for example:
`

```
const newTime = new Date('2019-02-19T06:00:00Z').toLocaleDateString('en-gb' {
year: 'numeric',
month: 'long',
day: 'numeric'
}); // 18 February 2019`
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how to use it for Z timezone